# Deleted the .wine folder and lost all my data

Tags: wine, backup, users, data-recovery, hidden-files

HELP! I deleted the .wine folder from my user folder and i've lost all my data. How can i get my files back? What happened?
I use Ubuntu 12.04! i don't know much about ubuntu yet.
Thank You

Comment: What do you mean, "all your data"?

Comment: Well, your `.wine` folder contains your "virtual" `C:` drive, if you deleted that, you have lost your programs and settings for wine applications. I suggest to bite the bullet and be more careful the next time. Oh, and if it is really important, back it up.

Comment: All my data means most of my music, pictures and document folders. Also lost most of my desktop folders and files. What i find strange is some of the folders (just a few of them) still contain some files. Is there any way i can recover my stuff?

Comment: How did you delete the .wine directory?

Comment: I went to my /user folder, then clicked "show hidden files" and I thought that /.wine was just the wine program folder so I deleted it. I previously unistalled wine through software center.

Comment: So you selected the folder and hit the delete button? If so, check you trash bin!

Comment: I deleted everything from my trash bin by accident. Is it possible that 180GB are simply gone in less than one minute? And why does the /.wine folder contain my c: drive? If it's just a "virtual" c: how come that by deleting this folder it directly affects my data on c:? 
Excuse me for my ignorance. I appreciate your help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem as you did. Since the .wine folder are actually linked with Documents folder, it's probably gone. However, you can try to recover some of the files by referring to this page http://www.webupd8.org/2009/03/recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-debian.html. Hope it can help.